# records and array with POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I try to reproduce Oracle complex type records.

Obviously I have to create database type because I cannot create complex type inside the pgsql declaration.

```
create type my_type as (
   .....
);

DO $$
declare
  
  my_cursor cursor  (key varchar)
  for
    select civility, name, firstname, email, telephone
    from my_table
    where sender = key;

  a_type record;
  b_type record;
  c record;
  contact my_type;
  contacts my_type [];
  i numeric;

begin
  select name, road, zcode, town
  into strict a_type 
  from a_table

  i = 0;

  open my_cursor (a_type.name);
  loop
    fetch my_cursor into contact;
    exit when not found;
      contacts[i] = contact;
      i = i + 1;
  end loop;

  select a_type as infos, contacts  into strict b_type;
  select b_type as sender into strict c;

end $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

This does not cause any error. So now, I would like to display my c variable. Before the end, I add :

```
  raise notice '%', c.sender.infos.name;
```

There is an error I dont understand in this context :

```
cross-database references are not implemented: c.sender.infos.name
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres doesn't supports multiple dereferencing for record type. Following code is working:

```
do $$
declare r1 record; r2 record; r3 record; _r1 record; _r2 record;
begin
  select 10 as x, 20 as y into r1;
  select r1 as r1, 30 as z into r2;
  select r2 as r2, 40 as w into r3;
  raise notice '%', to_json(r3);
  _r2 := r3.r2;
  _r1 := _r2.r1;
  raise notice '%', _r1.x;

end;
$$;
NOTICE:  {"r2":{"r1":{"x":10,"y":20},"z":30},"w":40}
NOTICE:  10
DO
```

Comment: Do you know if I can work on the json object made by to_json ? because you code it is like I am doing r1.x,...not a point for me.

Comment: @mlwacosmos - what you want is not supported - you cannot to write r3.r2.x (unfortnatelly) for record type (some should to work on composites with known type). In new PostgreSQL 14 you can do `RAISE NOTICE '%', (to_jsonb(r3))['r2']['r1']['x']`